# Getting a handle on a huge classic asp project

Tags: asp-classic

I've been working with an ASP Classic site with over 500 files, some of which aren't used and some of which are; along with a database with hundreds of procs and functions and tables, in the same shape.

I need a way to get a grip on the project so I can eventually migrate it. I don't have time yet to walk through every single page and look at the SQL (stored procedures are in the database and are called properly within the ASP pages), so I'm at a loss as to how to get a handle on this.

My immediate thought is to make ASP classes and put them into the pages as I go - they'd pretty much be used for getting and setting fields, validation, and sending recordsets into display functions.

Is this a reasonable approach? Am I missing some strategy?

How would you approach this? A migration to another platform at this point is considered, but not feasible for the short term (next couple of months)

Comment: I've been trying to answer this question for awhile but I found I was struggling and finally realised why.  There is no clear question.  You say "I don't have time yet to walk through ..." but then later "My immediate thought is to make ASP classes and put them into the pages".  Well how can you even think about the latter without having done the former?

Comment: My plan is to walk through the active pages and try to consolidate the database calls into the class files, so there is only one place a proc is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simple advice is stop think about code.   Spend more time with the UI actually using it and spend time examining in detail the database schema.

**Edit**

If you are trying to determine what pages are active then use IIS logging to harvest distinct pages hit.  Also do some scripting to collect the names of files and text search the files in the site looking for any occurance of those files.  This info should identify parts of the site that are rarely used or dead.

However in all probability there will considerable content in the "active" files which are also dead. Let me re-iterate do not actually to add classes or refactor the code at this stage you should concentrate on understanding *what* it does not *how* it does it.  Understanding the DB Schema is a vital step and then understanding what UI interactions bring about specific changes in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to compile the project using http://aspclassiccompiler.codeplex.com/ or you can migrate to ASP.net MVC one page at a time (when needed) and using a mix of both in the meantime.